# Uvicorn not processing some requests randomly

Tags: nginx, python-asyncio, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

We are running a Fastapi + Uvicorn web application using gunicorn as a process manager and Nginx as the reverse proxy server. The application is running in async mode for most of the i/o operations (DB call, Rest apis). The whole setup is running inside a Docker container on Ubuntu 16.04.

The setup works most of the times but sometimes it does not process a request at all & it gets timed out at Nginx end. We also tried taking Nginx out of the setup and observed that few requests get processed after really long time (like after 15 mins). This is very random but usually happens 2-3 times in an hour.

Below is the gunicorn config that we are using –

```
host = os.getenv("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
port = os.getenv("PORT", "80")

# Gunicorn config variables
workers = web_concurrency
bind = f"{host}:{port}"
keepalive = 2

timeout = 60  
graceful_timeout = 30
threads = 2
worker_tmp_dir = "/dev/shm"
# Logging mechanism
capture_output = True
loglevel = os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "debug")
```

And gunicorn is invoked with command `exec gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -c "$GUNICORN_CONF" "$APP_MODULE"`

We have tried several config changes like –

1. Changing the number of workers, worker timeout
2. Changing the process manager from gunicorn to supervisord
3. Offloading the CPU intensive task to Celery instead of threading
4. Binding uvicorn app to unix socket instead of proxy server

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, have you identified the root cause ?

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar issue.  Opened a ticket here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3137

Comment: @TimOrme did you solve this?

Comment: @Crashalot We ended up just working around it by not using long-running clients.  Instead, we just created a new client to the server for each request.  This was for an internal service though, so we had the luxury of controlling the clients in this way.  It does seem like FastAPI should at least have some setting to kill connections after some amount of time if not receiving data, but I dont think thats currently possible.

There are some more details of the exact issue in the GitHub issue there.

Comment: This could be hitting an OS limit on the OS layer. Check your kernel messages you may be hitting a limit on the max connections / file descriptors. You can increase and monitor those limits https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ulimit-linux-command although I do not know how docker affect those limits, you may want to check inside and outside docker?